# How Can I draw Line between these Indicator ImageButton in JAVA Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to draw a line between these buttons programmatically because the user will determine where he/she be going so according to that information it should draw line between certain buttons. I am new to Android world and still learning it.
Thanks in advance

I have tried the canvas class available but I dont know how to display the line between the buttons and show it on my main activity.

[This is the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uABpj.jpg)

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748146/android-canvas-drawline . Also, how is the "map" rendered - a static image or are you using a map api?

Comment: I am using a static image